# Writing loop within GAMS and printing the results on one excel file

Tags: gams-math

I am solving a model in GAMS, which is a large model, call it "profit", but in which I wish to vary a particular parameter, call it alpha(j), where alpha represents parameters defined over different values of a set `j', and then see how the results for key variables change with it.

Call the loop index `i', and I wish to run the model by increasing alpha(j) by 0.05 each time, from the initial values of the full vector alpha(j), and then look at how the variables X and Y change:

```
Set        i          / 1*20/  ;
```

*In the above, I set the index from 1 to 20, and then the initial value of alpha for the first iteration as 0.

*I then write the loop

```
    loop(i, alpha(j,i+1)  =alpha(j)+0.05
    solve mymodel using lp maximizing profit;
);
```

*I then wish to write the results to an excel GDX file.

*Baseline

```
execute_unload "resultsloop.gdx"
X Y ; 

execute 'gdxxrw.exe resultsloop.gdx var=XXX rng=XXX   !a1'

execute 'gdxxrw.exe resultsloop.gdx var=X.L rng=X!a1'
execute 'gdxxrw.exe resultsloop.gdx var=Y.L rng=Y!a1'

;
```

There are two problems with this- one of which I have and the other which I can foresee.

1. The first issue is that I get an error "Dimension different - The symbol is referenced with more/less indices as declared". I am not sure how to address this issue.
2. The second issue (which I can foresee) is in the writing of the excel results. Ideally, I would like the results for each variable be stacked in a column, by loop number. As it currently stands, I will simply get a single excel file, with only the results corresponding to the end of the loop.

Any help on this is much appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About the first issue: That problem is probably caused by the assignment `alpha(j,i+1)  =alpha(j)+0.05`. As the error message says, for `alpha` you reference it with two dimensions on the left (`j,i+1`) and with one on the right (`alpha(j)`). One of this must be wrong. Compare it to your declaration (you did not share that here).

About the second issue: I would collect the results in one parameter in GAMS and write this all at once to Excel at the end, like in this dummy code:

```
parameter profitI(i)
          someIndexedOverJVarI(i,j);
loop(i, 
    alpha(j)  =alpha(j)+0.05;
    solve mymodel using lp maximizing profit;
    profitI(i) = profit.l;
    someIndexedOverJVarI(i,j) = someIndexedOverJVar.l(j);
);
execute_unload "results.gdx" profitI;
execute 'gdxxrw.exe results.gdx par=profitI rng=XXX!a1';
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I should have been more precise. In the original code. That being said- although the code you have presented here works wonders when printing results of scalars to excel (like profitI), it seems to not be well suited for variables defined over sets, such as, say, alpha(j). In the above, all that is printed is the value of the scalar profit, per loop value. I would like to say print the values of alpha(j) as well- any thoughts on this are much appreciated :)

Comment: That was meant just as example to show the principle, I'll extend my reply to include a indexed variable as well